# Facebook Pixel not tracking properly with data that doesnt make sense. How do i fix it?

Tags: facebook

I have created a fb advert for a product on my shopify store. I have previously installed the pixel in shopify store preferences as instructed at set up, and i have also put in the tracking code as instructed by fb ads manager in the checkout settings of shopify setting, pasted below:

fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: 1,
    currency: 'gbp',
  });

On the ad reporting it says that overnight, 4 purchases were made, 4 checkouts initiated, 4 payment details entered, 4 add to baskets... but in my shopify account, no sales have been made or registered on the store.

Shopify says that there is no issue with the checkout process, and Facebook says the pixel is tracking properly and that there must be an error with this code and how it's entered, but they cant help me fix it.

It appears as though these 4 people added the product to cart and went all the way through the checkout process and stopped before pressing BUY. But i need to know how to fix the code so the facebook ads manager can report the data correctly and not count these interactions as purchases as its very misleading...

Please help me fix this :)
thanks
sam

Comment: This is quite un-specific ... Please go read [ask], and add more relevant details. Have you checked your implementation and how it behaves during the checkout process using the FB pixel helper extension already?

Comment: Yes the pixel helper just shows all the data parameters on every page so doesnt actually help, if anything it makes it worse because even on the product page it shows the data collected for all parameters of the following: AddPaymentInfo
ViewContent
PageView
Microdata
Purchase
AddToCart
AddToCart
InitiateCheckout
Search
ViewContent. im not sure what other details i can add? i implemented everything as instructed and its tracking all events on every click and making all reporting redundant and dont know how to fix it...